# after reset blender and when added new objects that could not been seen.

Tags: blend-files

Hi can anyone helped to check out what's wrong on the script, thanks
After reset blender and when  added new objects that could not been seen. 
used the blender console implement the script it works good.
but use .py got the result the object had been added turn out to be a orange point. 
the first generated file test0309.blend is ok. But the second generated file test0309_2.blend the sphere only show as an orange point.

```
import bpy
import os
import bmesh
import math
import mathutils
def reset_blend():
    bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings()
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        for obj in scene.objects:
            scene.objects.unlink(obj)
    # only worry about data in the startup scene
    for bpy_data_iter in (
            bpy.data.objects,
            bpy.data.meshes,
            #bpy.data.lamps,
           # bpy.data.cameras,
    ):
        for id_data in bpy_data_iter:
            bpy_data_iter.remove(id_data)         
def main():
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=10,location = ( 0, 0, 0))
    output_filepath=os.path.join(bpy.path.abspath("//"),"test0309.blend")
    bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=output_filepath)
    reset_blend()
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=10,location = ( 1, 1, 1))
    output_filepath1=os.path.join(bpy.path.abspath("//"),"test0309_2.blend")
    bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=output_filepath1)
    reset_blend()
```

Comment: You're looping over `bpy_data_iter` and modifying the collection at the same time. That's a recipe for trouble.